# Spark csv data validation failed for date and timestamp data types of Hive

Tags: csv, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Hive Table Schema:

```
c_date                  date                                        
c_timestamp             timestamp
```

*It's text table*

Hive Table data:

```
hive> select * from all_datetime_types;
OK
0001-01-01  0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000001
9999-12-31  9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999999
```

csv obtained after spark job:

```
c_date,c_timestamp
0001-01-01 00:00:00.0,0001-01-01 00:00:00.0
9999-12-31 00:00:00.0,9999-12-31 23:59:59.999
```

**Issues:**

- `00:00:00.0` is added in date type
- timestamp is truncated to milliseconds precision

Useful code:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf(true).setMaster("yarn-cluster").setAppName("SAMPLE_APP");
SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);
HiveContext hc = new HiveContext(sc);
DataFrame df = hc.table("testdb.all_datetime_types");
df.printSchema();
DataFrameWriter writer = df.repartition(1).write();
writer.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save(outputHdfsFile);
```

---

I am aware of `dateFormat` option. But `date` and `timestamp` column can have different formats in Hive.

**Can I simply covert all columns to String?**

Comment: Can you share the output of `df.printSchema()`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `timestampFormat` option in spark to specify your time stamp format.

```
spark.read.option("timestampFormat", "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a").csv("path")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I can't put a hardcoded timestamp format as I mentioned in the end of the question.

Comment: Is there any way to stored nanosecond timestamp in spark 1.6?

Comment: You mentioned date and timestamp have different formats and you can use them both

Answer (score 0):

Spark supports up to nanoseconds precision of Timestamp. You can probably try mapping date and timestamp columns like below,

```
DataFrame df = hiveContext.sql("select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyy-MM-dd'), from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS') from table")
```