# How to covert dataframe datatypes to String?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a hive Table having `Date` and `Timestamp` datatypes. I am creating `DataFrame` using below java code:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf(true).setMaster("yarn-cluster").setAppName("SAMPLE_APP");
SparkContext sc = new SparkContext(conf);
HiveContext hc = new HiveContext(sc);
DataFrame df = hc.table("testdb.tbl1");
```

Dataframe schema:

```
 df.printSchema
root
 |-- c_date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- c_timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

I want to covert these columns to String. How can I achieve this?

I need this because of issue : [Spark csv data validation failed for date and timestamp data types of Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42979217/spark-csv-data-validation-failed-for-date-and-timestamp-data-types-of-hive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
df.withColumn("c_date", df.col("c_date").cast(StringType))
```

Answer (score 2):

In scala, we generally cast datatypes like this:

```
df.select($"date".cast(StringType).as("new_date"))
```